# Error validating access token with bot messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-access-token, facebook-messenger-bot, messenger

I'm trying to send messages through FB messenger API. 
It returns:

> Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated
>   because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the
>   session for security reasons.

Does anyone know how to figure it out?

Thank you

Comment: Figure what out exactly? If your token was invalidated, go get a new one …

Comment: It works ! Sorry for that stupid question :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to re-assign the Facebook Page again to get a new token.